# How do you pass a variable from Program.CS to a Controller in .NET Core 2.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I will apologize in advance that I am a complete novice with .NET so please bear with me. My goal is to simply be able to pass variables from my Program class to a controller in my setup.

**Program.cs**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace EJ2FileManagerService
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Run();
        }
        public static IWebHost CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                     .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
                     {
                         var test = "results"; 
                     })
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();
    }
}
```

I want to be able to consume the variable `test` in my `TestController` class. It is located under Controllers/TestController.cs.

**TestController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;

namespace EJ2FileManagerServices.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    
    public class TestController : Controller
    {
    
    // WANT TO READ TEST VARIABLE HERE

        // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }
        // GET api/values/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason you can't define a property in the TestController directly? What are you gaining from passing from Program.cs? You could look at Startup.cs and adding a service to return your value by dependency injection. It's worth reading the ASP .Net Core documentation to understand the workflow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/introduction-to-aspnet-core?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: Grammar police - http://www.queens-english-society.com/bear-with-me-or-bare-with-me (it's too cold here for what you suggest :) )

Comment: More seriously reading "config" section of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0 is likely what you are after.

Comment: I guess whatever answer would be given to that question will be wrong. It would be best if you gave more context so that people can guide you in the right direction. Where does this variable´s value originate? Is it provided by an environment variable, or will it be read from a configuration file, or is it a command-line option?

Answer (score 0):

This was simply just user error -- the first comment was correct I just needed to do my calls and actions inside the controller versus inside of Program.cs.

Thanks!